How do you transform a typescript object to another type, without using type casting?
I have a mapped type that maps strings/numbers/booleans to "tagged" versions of those types:
interface TaggedString {
  type: "string";
  value: string;
}

interface TaggedNumber {
  type: "number";
  value: number;
}

interface TaggedBoolean {
  type: "boolean";
  value: boolean;
}

type TaggedType<T> = T extends string
  ? TaggedString
  : T extends number
  ? TaggedNumber
  : T extends boolean
  ? TaggedBoolean
  : never;

type TaggedObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: TaggedType<T[K]>;
};

But when the time comes to actually create the tagged javascript object, I can't think of a type-safe way to generate it. This is the function I've been using:
const createTaggedObject = <T extends object>(input: T): TaggedObject<T> => {
  const result: any = {};

  for (const key in input) {
    if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = input[key];
      if (typeof value === "string") {
        result[key] = { type: "string", value };
      } else if (typeof value === "number") {
        result[key] = { type: "number", value };
      } else if (typeof value === "boolean") {
        result[key] = { type: "boolean", value };
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
};


Since I have to loop through the original objects keys, I have to create the tagged object key-by-key. This means the object can't be initialized with the type I ultimately want!
Is there a way around this?
typescript playground

This is essentially the same as this question about mapping tuples except you're iterating over object keys/entries instead of a tuple. But it's the same underlying problem: TS doesn't strongly type "map each piece of this to that" in a way that works for situations like this, and when the type of the pieces vary then it can't even express it.  You need type assertions (what you're calling "casting") somewhere, so you might as well do what you're doing. Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

@jcalz you know, I think that does answer my question. Thanks for the link to the other question, it clears things up a lot.
I try to take type inference as far as I can, but this one might just have to get the unit test treatment. Thanks so much!

Yeah, it's unfortunate. The best I can ever do in these situations is to try to package the type assertions inside some vaguely reusable function, like objectMapper in this playground link, but that is observably worse if you don't plan to reuse objectMapper. And there's still type assertions when you use it for generics.
